# CodeIgniter Form Validation Issue

Tags: php, jquery, validation, codeigniter-3

So I am validating a form using code igniter which simplifies my code a lot however I am facing a new problem. My form at first gets loaded as a pop up inside a view. But when the controller returns response after validation then the form opens as a separate webpage instead of just loading inside the previous view.

main_view.php

```
<script>
 function div_show(type, classID) {    
   if(type=='adduser')
   {
     document.getElementById('AddUser_popup').style.display = "block";
     $("#AddUser_popup").load("add_user");
   }
 }
</script>
<body>
  <button id="popupNewTerm" onClick="div_show('adduser', null)">Add user</button>
  <div class="AddUser_popup" id="AddUser_popup">  </div>
</body>
```

Controller:

```
public function add_user()
{
    $data = array();
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->model('user_m');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username', 'required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('emp_email','E-mail', 'required|trim|valid-email|xss_clean');

    if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('includes/forms/add_user', $data);
    }
    else {
        $data['username']=$this->input->post('username');
        $data['emp_email']=$this->input->post('emp_email');


        $user=array(
            'user_id'=> NULL,
            'username'=> $data['username'],
            'emp_email'=>$data['emp_email']
        );
        $this->user_m->insert_user($user);
        $this->load->view('includes/forms/add_user', $data);
    }
}
```

Form-> (add_user.php)

```
<div id="popupContact">
 <?php

 if(isset($username) && isset($emp_email))
 {
     echo validation_errors();
     echo 'User added successfully!';
 }
 else {
    echo validation_errors();
    echo form_open('', 'id="form" name="form"');
    echo '<p id="close" onclick ="div_hide()">X</p>';
    echo '<h2>Add User</h2>';
    echo '<hr>';
    echo '<label for="username">Username: </label>'.form_input('username', set_value('username')) .'&nbsp;&nbsp;';
    echo '<label for="emp_email">Email: </label>'.form_input('emp_email', set_value('emp_email')) . '<br><br>';


    echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit', 'id="submit"');

    echo form_close();
 }
 ?>
</div>
```

how can I load the form inside the main_view.php after the validation fails from the controller and when the validation is successful, I want the form to close inside the main page. I can do form validation using normal javascript and php but wanted to learn code igniter method of validation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an issue in Validation regarding Codeigniter, then please read [CodeIgniter Official Form Validation Guide](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html?highlight=validation)

I recommend **Saving Sets of Validation Rules to a Config File**

If you are still confuse the read/review the piece of below code, it will help you. This code is used in Config File.

```
<?php

$config = array(
    'master/user' => array(
        array(
            'field' => 'empname',
            'label' => 'Employee Name',
            'rules' => 'required|trim|min_length[6]|xss_clean'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'cnt',
            'label' => 'Contact Number',
            'rules' => 'required'
        ),
        array(
            'field'=>'dob',
            'label'=>'Date Of Birth',
            'rules'=>'required'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'design',
            'label' => 'Designation',
            'rules' => 'required'
        ),
        array(
            'field'=>'pass',
            'label'=>'Password',
            'rules'=>'required'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'cpass',
            'label' => 'Password Confirmation',
            'rules' => 'required|trim|min_length[6]|matches[pass]|xss_clean'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'email',
            'label' => 'Email',
            'rules' => 'required'
        ),

//        array(
//            'field' => 'prof',
//            'label' => 'Profile Image',
//            'rules' => 'required|callback_upload_image'
//        )
    ),
    'master/SAdmin' => array(
        array(
            'field' => 'empname',
            'label' => 'Employee Name',
            'rules' => 'required|trim|min_length[6]|xss_clean'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'cnt',
            'label' => 'Contact Number',
            'rules' => 'required'
        ),
        array(
            'field'=>'dob',
            'label'=>'Date Of Birth',
            'rules'=>'required'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'design',
            'label' => 'Designation',
            'rules' => 'required'
        ),
        array(
            'field'=>'pass',
            'label'=>'Password',
            'rules'=>'required'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'cpass',
            'label' => 'Password Confirmation',
            'rules' => 'required|trim|min_length[6]|matches[pass]|xss_clean'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'email',
            'label' => 'Email',
            'rules' => 'required'
        )

    ),
    'master/task' => array(
        array(
            'field' => 'jtitle',
            'label' => 'Job Title',
            'rules' => 'required|trim|xss_clean'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'jnature',
            'label' => 'Job Type',
            'rules' => 'required'
        ),
        array(
            'field'=>'assigne',
            'label'=>'Assigned From',
            'rules'=>'required'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'assignto',
            'label' => 'Assign To',
            'rules' => 'required'
        ),
        array(
            'field'=>'ddate',
            'label'=>'Due Date',
            'rules'=>'required'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'reminder',
            'label' => 'Reminder',
            'rules' => 'required|trim|max_length[1]|xss_clean'
        ),
//        array(
//            'field'=>'image',
//            'label' => 'Image',
//            'rules' => 'required'
//        )
//       

    )
);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion